# msdeploy.exe: Deploy only changed files

Tags: iis, msdeploy, webdeploy, webdeploy-3.6

I am using msdeploy.exe for deploying my project to remote iis site using below command

```
msdeploy.exe -source:iisApp="D:\publish" -dest:iisApp="test-site",ComputerName="https://url:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=test-site",UserName="u",Password="p",IncludeAcls='False',AuthType='Basic' -verb:sync -enablerule:AppOffline -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -retryAttempts:20 -allowUntrusted='True'
```

But it is always uploading each an every file during deployment.

Is there any way so that i can upload only changed files using msdeploy.exe?

Answer (score 2):

Solved using `-useChecksum` paremeter